# The index won't print in the PDF

Tags: indexing

I am using texworks, which I think uses LaTeX 2e.
I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt,latexsym]{book}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Write something\index{something}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

This produces  `.PDF` file and a `.idx` file, but the index never gets printed in the PDF.  How can I get the index to print?

Answer (score 2):

The documentclass option `latexsym` is not a valid option. Hence your MWE will be as given below with a name say `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Write something\index{something}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

In order to generate an index out of this TeX file you should go through the following process:

```
pdflatex test
makeindex test
pdflatex test
pdflatex test
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `makeindex` on the file.  Your editor may have an option to do this for you, you can configure `latexmk` to do it, or you can run it from the command line.

For instance, in `texstudio` there is an option `index` under the `tools` menu.